# C++ Snake Game: Trouble with input buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

I am working on recreating the snake game in C++ for personal practice to play in CMD.exe

[Imgur Link: Snake CMD Window Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLkB4.jpg)

Below is the section of code that is giving me trouble:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    bool good = false; //just a flag I use to check for valid inputs

    //some code that draws to the screen a simple UI for snake

    cout << "Press START";

    while(!good){                                  //while input is not a "valid" input
        if(GetKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000){       //if the return key has been pressed
            good = true;                           //the input is valid
        }
    }

    //The rest of the game logic

    return 0;
}
```

I want my game to wait to start until the player has pressed the return key on their keyboard.
The problem is that when I test out my program I enter keys beforehand that are not the return key ("a", "v", "7", "Spacebar"). Then when I finally press the return key the program does continue as intended, but it also inputs the previously typed characters as well. Because I'm running my code inside of CMD, I get a message saying " 'av7' is not recognized as an internal or external command".

[Imgur Link: Snake CMD Window Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lKHv.jpg)

I think the reason for this is because the input buffer is combining each input together because I am not clearing the input buffer when the pressed key is NOT the return key.

However, I just needed to double check and post this here to get a definite answer as to why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: `GetKeyState` is for Windows programs only. It doesn't tell you the key state. It tells you what the key state was when the last Windows Message was generated. Does your program use Windows Messages, no, so it's nonsense.

Comment: I see, so how can I properly check for the return key being pressed in CMD without relying on Windows Messages?

Comment: The console system in Windows is basically separate from everything else. You could try using GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents to see whether there is input. If there is input, you can then read it using ReadConsoleInput. Alternatively there is _kbhit and _getch. Don't mix and match as it will cause problems (e.g. don't use _kbhit and ReadConsoleInput). I haven't done this recently so I'm not sure if I remember it correctly.

Comment: @user253751 GetAsyncKeyState should work in a console program.

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. GetAsyncKeyState absolutely works! I changed my code up a little as well. I hear that it is acceptable practice to use a do-nothing loop as I'm really only making this code for myself just to practice, I know it's probably bad for other things, but that is not the focus right now. I ended up using a while loop checking if GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) & 0x8000 is equal to 0

Comment: [`_kbhit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit) (non-blocking) or [`_getch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch) (blocking).

Comment: The code cannot reproduce the behavior that '*input*' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. As far as the code concerned, It just always check the status of ***VK_RETURN*** virtual key.